# Prove that $\left|\left(0,\infty\right)\right|=\left|\mathbb{R}\right|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

So this is pretty obvious in what it is asking: To prove that anything between $0$ and infinity are part of the positive reals.

I feel kind of stupid for asking but I just don't even know where to start. The topic this question comes under is countable sets and bijections, not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: take $f(x) = e^x$ which is clearly a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that two sets have the same cardinality, you must show that there is a bijection between them. In your case, you must find a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and the set $(0,\infty)$; that is, a $1-1$ and onto function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,\infty)$. For example, the function $e^x$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is an example: all of its values are in $(0,\infty)$, every positive value is attained, and no value is attained twice.